# Does Ryanair transfer checked luggage to its final destination on connecting flights?

Tags: ryanair, stopovers, low-cost-carriers

I'd like to fly from Brno (CZ) to Riga (LT) via Milan-Bergamo (IT), and both legs are with Ryanair, with a sensible 2h45 layover.

Does Ryanair handle my checked-in luggage like other airlines, so that it arrives directly to the final destination?

According to [this article](https://www.irishtimes.com/business/transport-and-tourism/ryanair-offers-connecting-flights-for-the-first-time-1.3039316), they offered this service in Rome Fiumicino two years ago, with plans to expand. However, I didn't find anything in the FAQ section of ryanair.com.

Comment: What date are you intending to fly on? In the coming weeks, flights on the two legs are not on the same weekdays so a connection is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Making-a-reservation/Connecting-flights) Milan-Bergamo is currently one of the three airports where luggage can be checked through. The implied constraint seems to be that the journey is booked as a connecting flight, there's no information about being able to do this if you book the flights separately.

However, it seems that this particular route can't be booked as a connecting flight at the moment - there's a list of some of the flights that can be booked as connections [here](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/connecting-flights-service-from-milan-and-rome-extended-with-27-more-routes/). They can be booked in exactly the same way as a single flight through the Ryanair website.

> **Checked Baggage**
>
> Checked baggage fees will be charged per sector of each journey.
>   Ryanair will be able to transfer your baggage to your final
>   destination at Fiumicino, Milan Bergamo and Porto airports only. In
>   the event of disruptions leading to your flight being diverted to
>   another airport, or where you are being re-routed via a different
>   airport, Ryanair will be unable to transfer your baggage. As a result,
>   you will need to collect your baggage at the intermediate airport and
>   re-check-in at the check-in desk.

In summary, this seems to mean you'll have to book two separate tickets, and collect your luggage at Milan on this itinerary.

Comment: Thanks @Miff, but how does one book connecting flights?

Comment: https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/connecting-flights-service-from-milan-and-rome-extended-with-27-more-routes/ give lots of details (your "sensible lay-over" timing is actually only marginally over the 150 minutes they specify as a minimum!).  Whilst they say this works with a single booking reference, there is no clear way on their website to actually book a connecting flight.  As their contact call centre is usually stupidly expensive to call, I suggest you use their on-line chat service (which is free)

Comment: FWIW I would warn against non-guaranteed connecting flights on budget airlines unless you're fine with the prospect of paying again in the event of a delay. I find (in my anecdotal experience at least) that delays on budget airlines are likely and long, and they're unlikely to bend the rules to help you like a traditional (European) airline might...